# Wrong Position with BorderLayout/GridBagLayout(Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, panel, gridbaglayout, border-layout

I have a Problem with my code.

When I launch it, 2 panels are overlapingeven though, I declared one Panel as North and one as South.

EingabePanel is suppose to be on top and SchnittpunktPanel is suppose to be on the bottom.

here is the code, maybe someone can help me. 
It's the first time I'm working on an GUI

package P2_pruefung.Frame;

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import P2_pruefung.Frame.Funktionen.CustomMath;
import P2_pruefung.Frame.Funktionen.MyActionListener;
import P2_pruefung.Objekte.Ungleichung;
import P2_pruefung.Objekte.UngleichungListe;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LinearFrame extends JFrame{

    LayoutManager design1 = new BorderLayout();
    LayoutManager design2 = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints rules  = new GridBagConstraints(); 
    public static JTextField tf_a = null;
    public static JTextField tf_b = null;
    public static JTextField tf_c = null;
    public static JTextField tf_g = null;
    public static JTextField tf_h = null;

    public static JPanel eingabe = null;
    public static JPanel schnittp = null;
    public static JPanel grafik = null;
    public static JPanel rechnen = null;

    public static UngleichungListe unge = new UngleichungListe();
    public static double g = 1;
    public static double h = 1;

    public LinearFrame(){
        // Voreinstellung des Fensters
        super("Lineare Optimierung");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(1024,760);
        this.setLocation(400,250);

        JPanel oben = EingabePanel();
        this.add(oben, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel schnittp = SchnittpunktePanel();
        this.add(schnittp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public JPanel EingabePanel() {
        //Voreinstellungen für das Panel
        eingabe = new JPanel();
        eingabe.setLayout(design2);
        rules.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        rules.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;



        //Inhalt des Panels

        // 1.Label 
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Bitte geben sie füre eine Ungleichung \"ax + bx <= c\" jeweils a, b und c ein");
        rules.gridx = 1;
        rules.gridy = 1;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(label1, rules);

        // Eingabe


        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("a = ");
        rules.gridx = 2;
        rules.gridy = 2;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(label2, rules);



        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(" b = ");
        rules.gridx = 3;
        rules.gridy = 2;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(label3, rules);

        JLabel label4 = new JLabel(" c = ");
        rules.gridx = 4;
        rules.gridy = 2;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(label4, rules);

        tf_a = new JTextField();
        rules.gridx = 2;
        rules.gridy = 3;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(tf_a, rules);

        tf_b = new JTextField();
        rules.gridx = 3;
        rules.gridy = 3;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(tf_b, rules);

        tf_c = new JTextField();
        rules.gridx = 4;
        rules.gridy = 3;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(tf_c, rules);

        JButton hinzu = new JButton("hinzufügen");
        rules.gridx = 4;
        rules.gridy = 4;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(hinzu, rules);
        hinzu.addActionListener(MyActionListener.getInstance());

        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Bitte geben sie für eine Zielfunktion \"f(x;y) = gx + hx\" jeweils g und h ein");
        rules.gridx = 1;
        rules.gridy = 5;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(label5, rules);

        JLabel label6 = new JLabel("g = ");
        rules.gridx = 2;
        rules.gridy = 6;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(label6, rules);

        tf_g = new JTextField("1");
        rules.gridx = 2;
        rules.gridy = 7;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(tf_g, rules);

        JLabel label7 = new JLabel("h = ");
        rules.gridx = 3;
        rules.gridy = 6;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(label7, rules);

        tf_h = new JTextField("1");
        rules.gridx = 3;
        rules.gridy = 7;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(tf_h, rules);

        JButton akt = new JButton("Aktualisieren");
        rules.gridx = 4;
        rules.gridy = 7;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(akt, rules);
        akt.addActionListener(MyActionListener.getInstance());

        return eingabe;
    }

    public JPanel SchnittpunktePanel(){

        //Voreinstellung des Panels
        schnittp = new JPanel();
        schnittp.setLayout(design2);
        rules.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        rules.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Folgende Schnittpunkte des Lösungsploynoms sind bekannt: ");
        rules.gridx = 1;
        rules.gridy = 1;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(label1, rules);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("");
        rules.gridx = 2;
        rules.gridy = 2;
        rules.weightx = 1;
        rules.weighty = 1;
        eingabe.add(label2, rules);

        int anz = unge.getSize();
        boolean test = false;
        Ungleichung[] id = new Ungleichung[anz];
        String eingabe = "";

        for( int i = 0; i <= anz; i++){
            for ( Ungleichung s: unge.UngeListe){
                if(s.getI() == i) {
                    id[i] = s;
                }
            }       
        }

        for( int i = 0; i <= anz; i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < anz; j++){
                double[] spunkt = CustomMath.getSchnittpunkt(id[i], id[j]);
                if(spunkt == null) //nichts tun
                for(Ungleichung s: unge.UngeListe){
                    if(s.checkUngleichung(spunkt[0], spunkt[1])){
                        test = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        test = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(test){
                    eingabe = eingabe + "(" + (Math.round(spunkt[0]*100)/100) + ";" + (Math.round(spunkt[1]*100)/100) + "), ";
                }
            }
        }




        return schnittp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the `BorderLayout`, but the `GridBagLayout`

Comment: Please edit your question to state what you expect to see vs. what you actually see.

Comment: EingabePanel is suppose to be on top and SchnittpunktePanel is suppose to be down. but they are both on top

Answer (score 0):

You should add components not to JFrame itself, but to JFrame.getContentPane().

```
this.getContentPant().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.getContentPant().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new EingabePanel());
this.getContentPant().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new SchnittpunktePanel());
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I tried it, but i get the error 
"The method add(String, Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (String, 
  EingabePanel)"

Comment: @MasterSansai : glad you found the bug yourself. It is recommended though to add component to JFrame.getContentPane() instead of to JFrame itself, to utilize double buffering for paint performance. Also it's better to stick to Swing component for many advantages it offers. FYI an article written by Amy Fowler (Sun's AWT and Swing architect): [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, thanks for the help. I found it out myself. the problem was this part of code:

```
schnittp = new JPanel();
    schnittp.setLayout(design2);
    rules.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    rules.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Folgende Schnittpunkte des Lösungsploynoms sind bekannt: ");
    rules.gridx = 1;
    rules.gridy = 1;
    rules.weightx = 1;
    rules.weighty = 1;
    eingabe.add(label1, rules);
```

I didn't add the labels to the Panel "schnittp", but to the Panel "eingabe"